# down-voting possible after the question is closed?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, closed-questions

There are 2 questions on down-votng and closed questions.

Is it **POSSIBLE** to down vote a question after the question is closed?

Also, is it required that the question **CAN** be down voted after the question is closed?

Comment: I do not understand your second question: no one requires anyone to vote, if that's the question. Otherwise, please try and edit it to make it clearer…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to vote on a closed question and its answers. In particular, it is possible to downvote the question, but it's also possible to upvote it.

A different question would be: is it desirable to downvote a question after it's closed? It's a matter of opinion, and mine is that, if the question score is already negative, there is no reason to pile on downvotes.

Comment: There *are* good reasons for this... When you reach a certain threshold, questions are pushed off of the home page. A score of -1 or -2 isn't enough for this, though. Remember that *downvotes are not for punishing users*, they're for ranking content.